# Exclude Meta Pixel Traffic from Staging Server on Subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, google-tag-manager, event-tracking, facebook-pixel

I have a meta / facebook pixel configured. I have my domain `mydomain.com` & a staging server on `staging.mydomain.com`. When i whitelist `mydomain.com`, facebook will also allow the subdomain `staging.mydomain.com` to send data, which i dont want.

I tried adding `www.mydomain.com` to facebook, because that's technically a more specific subdomain of `mydomain.com`, but facebook will autocorrect it into `mydomain.com`. What can I do here, to exclude the staging server?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Block list instead?

You can either use Allow list **or** Block list, not both together. So if your problem resides only in the staging subdomain, you can simply **block** it.

Although if you want to further narrow down other domains or their subdomains, this could become a problem.

[image]

Comment: yes, tried this and it does work, but it's not ideal, as it creates other problems, as you correctly mentioned  i'm a bit surprised that it seems like there isn't a better solution for this? do people not use staging servers / urls anymore? 

Comment: @antonwilhelm Can you just block the subdomain in the tag trigger? If you use GTM, it's very easy (hostname does not contain 'subdomain.')